# Type/Name of comma

Tags: commas, terminology, gapping, introductory-words

> Last month the science museum was opened, giving an insight into traditionally secret world of scientist.

What is the type/name of the comma above? (The one before 'giving')

Comment: Is that comma same as the one below?
' the dog waliked down the street happily, waving his tail with joy'

Comment: There are two errors in your sentence. Should be: "**the** traditionally secret world of scientist**s**".

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is a bracketing comma. "giving an insight into traditionally secret world of scientist" is simply additional, unnecessary information.

The sentence is also poorly written/wrong as "giving" is a dangling participle. (It sounds as if scientists opened the museum...)

The [The University of Sussex](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/summary#:%7E:text=There%20are%20four%20types%20of,gapping%20comma%20and%20bracketing%20commas.) has some advice, and gives a list of types of commas. The names of the types differ depending on who is teaching or where they are teaching. The names the University of Sussex uses may not be the ones you use:

> There are four types of comma: **the listing comma**, **the joining
> comma**, the **gapping comma** and **bracketing commas**.
>
> **A listing comma** can always be replaced by the word **and** or **or**:
>
> Vanessa seems to live on eggs, pasta and aubergines.
>
> **A joining comma** must be followed by one of the connecting words **and, or, but, yet or while**:
>
> The report was due last week, but it hasn't appeared yet.
>
> **A gapping comma** indicates that you have decided not to repeat some words which have already occurred in the sentence:
>
> Jupiter is the largest planet and Pluto, the smallest.
>
> **Bracketing commas** always come in pairs, unless one of them would come at the beginning or the end of the sentence, and they always set
> off a weak interruption which could in principle be removed from the
> sentence:
>
> My father, who hated cricket, always refused to watch me play.

There are others that can be added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Commas can serve various purposes, but I don't think they are normally spoken of as belonging to named types. Commas can be used to separate list items, set off relative clauses, surround parenthetical expressions, separate a month from a year in certain date formats, set off titles of address, and for various other purposes. But one does not speak of a list comma,  a relative comma, a parenthetical  comma, a date comm, or any other particular sort of comma. They are all just commas.

The one exception is the serial comma, sometimes called the "oxford comma". This is the final comma in a construction such as:

> A, B, V, and D.

It has a name because there has been much debate as to whether it is always, sometimes, or never to be used. But that is thje only named type of comma I can think of.

In the sentence

> Last month the science museum was opened, giving an insight into traditionally secret world of scientist.

the comma separates the main clause from a dependent clause.

Comment: Confusing. You don't need comma if the dependent clause comes after the independent clause. Right? You use comma only when the dependent clause comes first.